# Accessing the body of a post RESTful request

Tags: java, rest, http-post

I can completely read a post request (headers + raw body) using 
 `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` with an HttpHandler for it.

But I can't do the same using a `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceProvider`
I can read the headers, but I need the raw body data in the request be it plain text, xml,  or data-bytes. An InputStreamReader would be OK.

```
   @ServiceMode(value = javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode.MESSAGE) 
    @WebServiceProvider
    @BindingType(value = HTTPBinding.HTTP_BINDING) 
    public class MyRestHandler 
    implements Provider<Source> {

       @Resource
       protected WebServiceContext wsContext; // injected


       public Source invoke(Source source) {

          /* source happens to be null except for text/xml BODY type
           * in the incoming request.
           * In this case, source is a SAXSource*/

       }

    }
```

Addendum (after Peter Knego observation)

In [Java Web Services](http://books.google.com/books?id=694fvh2hdVEC&printsec=frontcover&hl=es&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) pages 126-138, the author presents a RESTful webservice
example where JAX-WS is used:

```
@ServiceMode(value = javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode.MESSAGE) 
@WebServiceProvider
@BindingType(value = HTTPBinding.HTTP_BINDING) 
public class RestfulTeams 
        implements Provider<Source> {  ... }
```

Even, in page it 136-137 it extends it to support the POST method, accessing
the body of the request. Clearly, it works with the JAX-WS library classes because it uses xml in the body request. Now I understand your surprise, and why `source` is always null but for text/xml bodies. Really, the easiest way was to use the JAX-RS library.

Comment: JAX-WS is a RESTful web service? When did this happen?

Comment: From the very beginning. A RESTful WS is a WS using HTTP verbs to encode the remote procedures calls and free HTTP body to pass data around (instead of SOAP-formated bodies)

Comment: @cibercitizen1  JAX-WS is for SOAP based services, JAX-RS implementations are for RESTful services.  Additionally, considering HTTP methods as a way "to encode the remote procedure calls" is missing the point of REST by quite a long way.

Comment: @Darrel. Well *for me* WS are essentially RPCs. Aren't? What's "the point"? Perhaps REST is a special way of doing RPC (stateless, transfer of the representation of a resource, use http verbs, ...) but the point is you are doing RPC.

Comment: @cibercitizen1  The significant difference of REST is that you are NOT doing RPC.  The term RPC has some specific connotations.  It means more than just "distributed interaction". The videos by Steve Vinoski here http://code.google.com/p/implementing-rest/wiki/Video explain it much better than I can.

Comment: @Darrel. I'm sorry but I can't see anything you can do with REST that couldn't be done with RPC. Only the *how* is different, but not the *what*.

Comment: @cibercitzen1 There is nothing in object-oriented programming that you can't do with procedural coding.  That doesn't mean that OO doesn't have value nor that it doesn't encourage a certain set of benefits.

Comment: @Darrel. Do you really think that RPC is to REST what procedural is to OO? For me, RPC (RMI, CORBA, ...) is clearly "higher level" than REST. Isn't it?

Comment: @cibercitizen1 REST is an architectural style, which IMHO is as high as you can go.  REST is so much more than just using HTTP methods to make requests to URLs.

Comment: @Darrel, Yes it is an style, but high? Compare                                "GET /operation?name=sum&a=1&b=2 HTTP/1.1" with "remoteRef.sum(1,2)" !

Comment: @cibercitizen1  I guess I'm not sure what you mean by "high".  And regarding your example, I'm not sure what you are trying to say other than, yes you can imitate RPC using HTTP.  That doesn't mean HTTP is limited to that style of interaction.

Comment: @Darrel, perhaps your are not sure, but I really am. Why did you start talking about HTTP? I think someone said "hey guys, SOAP RPCs is too complicated, let's use HTTP". He could have said "let's use sockets again" REST is far limited than RPC, in fact it is a restricted version of general RPCs (REST = stateless with a producer-consumer pattern of interaction). And worse, for each different application you have to choose the format of data passing around and do the marshalling yourself.

Comment: @cibercitizen1 Wow.  Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @cibercitizen1 Do you regularly spout nonsense? I'm glad you have your own definition of REST, but it might help if you share what that is. You are obviously not talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST. Darrel switched to HTTP b/c your example shows an example using URI tunneling, which is definitely not REST. There's nothing wrong with RPC. But REST, it ain't.

Comment: @Ryan. Thank you very much for your reply so kind. ("Do you regularly spout nonsense?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-RS) implementation, [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) for instance. Book:
[RESTful Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=_jQtCL5_vAcC&lpg=PP1&ots=cJdr7eTV1X&dq=jax-rs&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)